# Время создания файла

Tags: golang, файловая-система

Как определить время создания файла при помощи *Go?* `os.Stat()` не подходит, там можно узнать время изменения.

Comment: какая ос и файловая система у вас?

Comment: я планирую кроссплатформенно, поэтому хотелось бы узнать и для винды и для для Linux Debian 8 и 9

Answer (score 0):

Некоторые файловые системы хранят время создания в метаданных.

Если речь о linux то [для каждого из ваших файлов есть только 3 разных значения времени, как определено стандартом POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_08)

и тогда наверное это максимум что можно сделать:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "os"
  "syscall"
  "time"
)

func statTimes(name string) (atime, mtime, ctime time.Time, err error) {
  fi, err := os.Stat(name)
  if err != nil {
    return
  }
  mtime = fi.ModTime()
  stat := fi.Sys().(*syscall.Stat_t)
  atime = time.Unix(int64(stat.Atim.Sec), int64(stat.Atim.Nsec))
  ctime = time.Unix(int64(stat.Ctim.Sec), int64(stat.Ctim.Nsec))
  return
}

func main() {
  name := "my_file"
  atime, mtime, ctime, err := statTimes(name)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }
  fmt.Println(atime, mtime)
  fmt.Println(ctime)
  err = os.Chtimes(name, atime, mtime)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }
  atime, mtime, ctime, err = statTimes(name)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }
  fmt.Println(atime, mtime)
  fmt.Println(ctime)
}
```

Если речь о windows или других os (здесь уже нужно смотреть особенности файловой системы и её возможности)

Answer (score 0):

Параметр `btime` (от англ. «*birth time*», «время
рождения») поддерживается не всеми ОС и не всеми ФС.  Если вам повезло,
и ваши ОС и ФС их поддерживают, для *Unix*-систем используется
такой код:

```golang
import (
    // …
    "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
    // …
)

// …

var statx unix.Statx_t
err = unix.Statx(unix.AT_FDCWD, filename, 0, 0, &statx)
// Check err.

var t = time.Unix(statx.Btime.Sec, int64(statx.Btime.Nsec))
log.Printf("the birth time of the file %#q is %s", filename, t)
```

Для ОС *Windows* вам так или иначе придётся делать по-другому.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, подробнее https://github.com/djherbis/times

```
package main

import (
  "log"

  "github.com/djherbis/times"
)

func main() {
  t, err := times.Stat("myfile")
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err.Error())
  }

  log.Println(t.AccessTime())
  log.Println(t.ModTime())

  if t.HasChangeTime() {
    log.Println(t.ChangeTime())
  }

  if t.HasBirthTime() {
    log.Println(t.BirthTime())
  }
}
```

Comment: Насколько я вижу, этот пакет не показывает `btime` в _Linux._

Comment: Да, можно косвенно, через accessTime

Comment: `atime` и `btime` — вещи совершенно разные.  Ну да ладно, вопрос ваш, вам решать.

Comment: да, увидел проблему вроде как\